# Can the adjoint of unbounded operators bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

Can the adjoint of an unbounded operator be bounded? If not, how to show it? Examples are appreciated.

For instance, given an unbounded operator $V: \mathcal{K} \otimes \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{K} $, where $\mathcal{K}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ are Hilbert spaces, can its adjoint be bounded?

Answer (score 0):

on a Banach space $X$, the adjoint of $T: X \to X$ is an operator $S : X^* \to X^*$ such that for every $Y \subseteq X$ onto which $T$ is bounded, for every $y \in Y^*, x \in Y$  :  $$y(Tx) = (Sy)(x)$$

if $T$ is unbounded then there exists $\|y\| =\|x\| = 1$ and $x_n \to x$ such that $$y(Tx_n) \to \infty$$ hence  $$(Sy)(x_n) \to \infty$$